# Can´t print boolean (true, false), TypeError: must be str, not bool

Tags: python, macos

Tried to search for the issue but couldn't find it. Here is the code:

```
number1 = input("Hello, tell me one number! :")
number2 = input("Now the second number! :")

sum = (float(number1) + float(number2))/2
result1 = number1 <= number2

print("Number 1 is:" + number1 )
print("Number 2 is:" + number2 )
print("The average of {0} and {1} is {2}".format(number1, number2, 
sum))
print(number1 + "is smaller or equal than" + number2 + ":" + result1)
```

Error code is:

> print(number1 + "is smaller or equal than" + number2 + ":" + result1)
>   TypeError: must be str, not bool

Now I had a similar issue with the sum number, but I could fix it with the float(), but I cannot figure out how to print a simple true/false at the end.

Comment: convert it to a string in the print statement.  str(result1)

Comment: Well that was easy! Thank you so much and sorry for the beginner question.

Comment: why don't use the `format` method you used above?

Comment: I tried it with the format method from above but I got the same error.

Comment: You are comparing strings, not numbers, so '12' <= '5'. Convert your inputs to floats immediatly, treat them as numbers all along, and only convert back to strings when printing. And better yet, have a look at [format](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

Comment: Thank you for the link! Eager to learn :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use string casting

```
str(result1)
```

Comment: @pradeep, in this case.  This *does* answer the question. See the comments under the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your output expression:

```
number1 + "is smaller or equal than" + number2 + ":" + result1
```

... performs the `+` operation on a variety of data types.  In this case, you need each operand to be `string`.  Use `str(result1)` or `__repr__(result1)` to provide the required type.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a `bool` to a `str`

```
>>> "hello"+True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: must be str, not bool
>>> 'hello'+str(True)
'helloTrue'
```